# Maximizing chance of winning in dice game

Tags: probability

> Player $A$ rolls three $6$-sided dice and sums the outcome and player $B$ rolls a
>   $20$-sided dice. The player with the highest score wins. Which player
>   do you wish to be?

This question was asked to me in an interview. I was wondering if there's a quick way to solve the problem. Obviously you can compute $P(A > B)$ but this takes a lot of time. It's sort of hard to reason through this quickly since if $B$ rolls $1, 2,$ or $3$ then  $A$ is greater than or equal to $B$ with probability $1$. On the other hand if $B$ rolls $19$ or $20$, they're guaranteed to win.

I was wondering if there is some quick way to do this without enumerating all possibilities. Also, their expectations are the same, so that doesn't help much.

Thanks

Comment: [Here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2275683/144421) is a nice answer from [David K](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/139123/david-k) to your problem.

Comment: Does it matter?  If we replace each number $k$ on the $6$-sided dice by $7-k$ we see there is a one-to-one correspondence between rolls of $s$ and rolls of $21-s$, so it seems like a fair game to me.  Am I overlooking something?

Comment: @saulpatz Can you explain a little bit more on your comment? I don't quite understand the argument. I think you are saying there is a bijection between the outcomes but I don't see why this is true. For example, there's more than one way to get a sum of, say, $7$ with the three dice, but only one way to get this with the twenty sided dice. I've read both your explanation and someone else's explanation in the post my post was flagged duplicate with. I've thought about it for some time and still can't wrap my head around it